# Sequence and case in a select in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, sequence

I'm trying to do this query (in oracle) but I have some problems:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN deptno = '10' THEN scott.seq.nextval 
                                  || 'next10' 
         WHEN deptno = '20' THEN scott.seqnextval 
                                  || 'next20' 
         WHEN deptno = '30' THEN scott.seq.currval 
                                  || 'curr' 
       END col_1 
FROM   scott.emp;
```

I'm getting this results:

```
COL_1
----------------------------------------------
191next20
192curr
193curr
194next20
195curr
196curr
197next10
198next20
199next10
200curr
201next20
202curr
203next20
204next10
205next20
206next10
207next10
```

And this is what I think they should be:

```
COL_1
----------------------------------------------
191next20
192curr
193curr
194next20
194curr
194curr
197next10
198next20
199next10
199curr
201next20
201curr
203next20
204next10
205next20
206next10
207next10
```

So, why i get the next value of the sequence also when I should have the current value and not only when the case selects the next value?
Yeah, this could be done with a plsql script but I can't.

Thanks you!

Comment: Why do you use a sequence for this? What is it that you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: It is a sort of exercise, I need this for an ODI interface.

Comment: @Bolla - It sounds like you want to be using an analytic function to compute the numeric portion of your result, not a sequence.  But I'm having problems trying to understand the logic you're trying to implement particularly since there is no `ORDER BY` in your query so the order in which `DEPTNO` 30 rows are returned is indeterminant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  Per the Oracle [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm):

> The statements in a WHEN clause can modify the database and call
>   non-deterministic functions. There is no fall-through mechanism as in
>   the C switch statement

Notice it doesn't say the statements in the "true" WHEN clause.  So even if the when statement is false, the nextval will fire:

```
select
case when 1=0 then 'next ' || seq_id.nextval
     when 1=1 then 'curr ' || seq_id.currval
end col1
from dual;
```

I must admit this is different than I expected.

EDIT: 
See answer from ShannonSeverance

Comment: 1) The docs are not saying that the DB will willy nilly execute statements on the THEN side of a CASE clause. 2) The docs you reference are for CASE _statement_, not the CASE _expression_. OP's example is using the CASE expression. The expression is documented at: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm#i1033392.

Comment: Are you claiming that saying that, "The statements in a WHEN clause can modify the database and call non-deterministic functions" means that `case when false then insert into t values (1); else null; end case;` may end up inserting a new row into t?

Comment: @tbone: You are referencing an irrelevant part of the docs (CASE statement vs CASE clause) and you are interpreting even that (unrelated part) wrongly. A function that modifies the database can modify the database only if it is called. Even more `nextval` and `currval` are not functions.

Answer (score 10):

`Nextval` and `currval` are not functions, but are "[Sequence Pseudocolumns](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns002.htm)".

"Within a single SQL statement containing a **reference** to NEXTVAL, Oracle **increments the sequence once: For each row returned** by the outer query block of a SELECT statement. Such a query block can appear in the following places. ..." (emphasis added) [[*Oracle Database SQL Language Reference*, "How to Use Sequence Values"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50946)]

In other words, `seq.nextval` is not a function with a side affect, but a pseudocolumn that has a particular value per row. Once there is a single reference to `seq.nextval`, the value increments for every row, whether or not the value is used. The outcome OP is seeing is a peculiar to sequences, not case expressions. For example, same thing with decode:

```
SQL> select decode(deptno
  2         , 10, seq.nextval || 'next10'
  3         , 20, seq.nextval || 'next20'
  4         , 30, seq.currval || 'curr30')
  5  from emp;

DECODE(DEPTNO,10,SEQ.NEXTVAL||'NEXT10',20,SEQ.
----------------------------------------------
35next20
36curr30
37curr30
38next20
39curr30
40curr30
41next10
42next20
43next10
44curr30
45next20
46curr30
47next20
48next10
```

Comment: A good day, I learned something new ;)  I upvoted this, cannot remove my answer.