# Using sequences to create group ID

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I'm attempting to create group_ids based on a set of item_ids. The only indication that the item_ids are part of a single group is the fact that item_ids are sequential. For example, based on the first two columns below, the output I want is the third:

```
item  item_id   group_id
ABC   282       2
ABC   283       2
ABC   284       2
ABC   285       2
ABC   051       3
ABC   052       3
ABC   189       4
ABC   231       5
ABC   232       5
ABC   233       5
ABC   234       5
ABC   247       6
ABC   248       6
ABC   249       6
ABC   250       6
ABC   091       7
ABC   092       7
```

The group_id doesn't necessarily have to be sequential itself, it only has to be unique. I attempted this with the following code:

```
create sequence seq
   start with 1
   minvalue 1
   increment by 1
   cache 20;

select seq.nextval from dual; --to initialize the sequence

select 
   item,
   item_id,
   case when diff = 1 then seq.currval else seq.nextval end group_id
from
   (
       select
           item,
           item_id,
           (id - lag(id, 1, 0) over (order by 1) diff
       from
           (
               select
                   item,
                   item_id
               from
                   table
            )
    );
```

But get the following output:

```
item  item_id   group_id
ABC   282       2
ABC   283       3
ABC   284       4
ABC   285       5
ABC   051       6
ABC   052       7
ABC   189       8
ABC   231       9
ABC   232       10
ABC   233       11
ABC   234       12
ABC   247       13
ABC   248       14
ABC   249       15
ABC   250       16
ABC   091       17
ABC   092       18
```

When looking for the cause of the problem, I found an [excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810108/sequence-and-case-in-a-select-in-oracle) by user ShannonSeverance that details why my solution won't work. However, it didn't provide any suggestions on how to move forward.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem, because SQL tables are inherently unordered.  The following "should" logically work, although it won't in practice:

```
select ii.*, (item_id - rownum) as grp_id
from item_ids ii;
```

A sequence of item_ids in order minus the row number is constant.  You can use that for a group, at least for a given item.  To handle multiple items, concatenate the values together:

```
select ii.*, item||'-'||(item_id - rownum) as grp_id
from item_ids ii;
```

To really make this work, you need to add an `order by` -- this guarantees the ordering of the results from the `select`.  This might work, assuming that there are "holes" between the groups:

```
select ii.*, item||'-'||(item_id - rownum) as grp_id
from item_ids ii
order by item, item_id;
```

Otherwise, you need some other column to determine the proper ordering for the items.